# ORDER BY need to sort by last name in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
SQLHonorary = "SELECT TblMembers.LastName, TblMembers.FirstName, TblMembers.Status, [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName " & _
    "FROM TblMembers " & _
    "WHERE (((TblMembers.Status) = 'Honorary')) " & _
    "ORDER BY ((TblMembers.LastName); ACS )"
```

I'm trying to sort by last name, but getting errors, I'm not sure how to format the last line.  Error 3075 syntax errors, no matter what combination I do I get various errors.

Can't seem to find help on line for this.....

Thanks,

Comment: Ascending is default, furthermore, you cannot have anything after the statement terminator. You can make things a lot prettier with aliases.

Comment: what is the statement terminator?  I'm not familiar with aliases....

Comment: It is a semi-colon.

Comment: Aliases https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Access-SQL-FROM-clause-2a7d031c-6912-4e8c-a644-590940ddaed1

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLHonorary - 'SELECT LastName, FirstName, Status, ' & _
    'CONCAT(FirstName, " ", LastName) AS FullName FROM TblMembers ' & _
    'WHERE Status = "Honorary" ORDER BY LastName'
```

Comment: That does not work, I get syntax error.  Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm running this is Access VBA.

Comment: SQLHonorary = "SELECT TblMembers.LastName, TblMembers.FirstName, TblMembers.Status, [FirstName] & "" "" & [LastName] AS FullName " & _
    "FROM TblMembers " & _
    "WHERE (((TblMembers.Status) = 'Honorary')) " & _
    "ORDER BY TblMembers.LastName;"        'this was the solution I found that worked